# dot-product spherical

Tags: vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I want to calculate **dotproduct** of $ e_r *e_\phi $ **they are unit vectors in spherical**. where my spherical coordinates is $(r,\phi,\theta)$

My attempt is first to convert them to cartesian:

which gives: after som algebra $sin \phi cos\phi(1-1)= 0$.

I was thinking that I could do this in spherical coordinates directly without converting to cartesian?

Because $e_r$=(1,0,0) , 
$e_\phi$=(0,1,0)

Like $ e_r *e_\phi $= (1,0,0) **dot** (0,1,0)=0 ?

Comment: What is your *definition* of $e_r, e_{\phi}$?

Comment: Just so. There are two different dot products to consider here: the one in $xyz$-space and the one in $r\phi\theta$-space. If you’re asking what the dot product of the _images_ of $e_r$ and $e_\phi$ under the $xyz$ dot product is, then you’ll need to proceed as you did. If you’re asking about the dot product in $r\phi\theta$-space, it’s whatever you define it to be (most likely $0$ so that the basis vectors in that space are orthogonal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit vectors $\hat r$, $\hat \theta$, and $\hat \phi$ are mutually orthogonal.  To show explicitly that $\hat r$ and $\hat \phi$ are orthogonal, we take their inner product and observe that it is zero.

To that end we first write the spherical unit vectors in Cartesian coordinates as

$\hat r=\hat x\sin \theta \cos \phi+\hat y\sin \theta \sin \phi+\hat z \cos \theta$

and

$\hat \phi=-\hat x \sin \phi+\hat y\cos \phi$

Therefore, their inner product is given by

$$\begin{align}
\hat r \cdot \hat \phi&=\sin \theta(-\sin \phi \cos \phi+\sin \phi \cos \phi)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: I have to write it in cartesian to truly show that they are orthogonal? or can you simply say that  r dot theta = 0, r dot phi=0 etc, if they got no number in front of them

Comment: By definition, the inner product or orthogonal vectors is zero.   So, one need not expand these orthogonal vectors in a different (e.g., Cartesian) orthogonal basis set.  However, if one does so, they will, of course, still be orthogonal.